# Drag and Drop MP3 to ListView

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to support drag and drop for my app. I've seen other drag and drop examples but none for MP3. Can someone explain what I need to do? Thanks

Comment: `MP3` is a file just like any other file, just different extension. You should be able to implement a drag and drop just like with other file types. You didn't specify in your tags, is this a web application / desktop app / mobile?

Comment: How is mp3 different to the other things you've seen?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I didn't realize MP3 was like any other file/text. I'll get it figured out today. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `lstBrowsers` to your listview's name and you should be good to go.

**Add to _DragEnter Event**

```
   ' See if the data is a File(s).
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then

        ' Yup! Allow copy.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        lstBrowsers.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Highlight)

    Else

        ' Nope, Sorry Charlie!
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None

    End If
```

**Add to _DragLeave Event**

```
' Set back color back to normal
lstBrowsers.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Window)
```

**Add to _DragDrop Event**

```
' File types allowed ...
Dim strAllowed() As String = {".mp3"}

Dim strFiles() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())

For Each strPath In strFiles
    ' Do stuff
Next strPath
```